# What does this OpenFeint Developer Warning mean?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

I get the following OpenFeint iOS warning:

> OpenFeint Developer Warning:
>   Please make sure to provide a delegate to OpenFeint

Here is also a screenshot of the warning:

[image: OpenFeint Developer Warning: Please make sure to provide a delegate to OpenFeint]

what does this warning means?

Comment: Images are banned at my place. Can you write down the error or warning?

Comment: OpenFeint Developer  Warning:                                                        Please  make sure to provide a delegate to OpenFeint!

Comment: @Vaibhav Tekam: Huh? Do you use Lynx to surf SO?

Comment: @Tim Büthe: I guess they have a proxy that stops images from being downloaded.

Comment: You are right JeremyP. Those will be the IT guys from my office.

Comment: @JeremyP: Why would somebody do that? Ist this punishment? Are you in Jail? ;-) (Sorry for off topic chitchat)

Comment: @Tim:  I guess you'll have to ask Vaibhav about his IT people.  Yes, it is completely brain dead but the fact is it is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some OpenFeint class that you have an instance of, of which you need to set the delegate property to one of your classes that implements the delegate protocol before using the class.